# char integer addition results in gibberish

Tags: c, encryption

```
string encryp(const string msg, int n)
{
    string enMsg = msg;
    for(int i = 0; msg[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(enMsg[i] != 32)
            enMsg[i] += n;
    }
    return enMsg;
}     

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc > 2) return 1;
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Print the string to be encrypted: ");
    string msg = GetString();
    string enMsg = encryp(msg, n);
    printf("%s\n", enMsg);
}
```

I am doing the Caesar’s cipher exercise; the characters I am encrypting is turning into gibberish.
I suspect that it is because of out of range problem, because when enMsg[i] -= n, the code encrypted perfectly. How can I cope with this??

Comment: You have to wrap the alphabet so that if the shift is 3, you translate `z` to `c`, etc.  Your code translates it to the third character after `z`, which is not `c` in any known code set.  You also need to think what you're going to do with upper-case letters, lower-case letters, digits and punctuation. Your code skips blanks (but you should write `if (enMsg[i] != ' ')`, using a literal for blank, not the value 32).

Comment: Isn't it *supposed* to turn into gibberish? ;-) Really though, you probably want to add a check to modify letters only (between a and z) and if the result is past z, wrap it back around.